# Canon LBP2900 installation in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, printing

How to install Canon LBP2900 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It's an author Q/A style.

Comment: @KasiyA Oh, now it makes more sense! But then, some words of context would make it better.

Comment: @VarunMDas I had commented that the answer did not say much, but KasiyA explained that it made sense (I didn't downvote). But I still think that the question would be much better with some context, also making the answer easier to find.  Two things where good to know: In what way is the printer, or the related software, special in terms of installing. And following from that, a reader with a similar printer should have some hint wheter this can be at helpful for him. Of course, if you mis or ignore all this, your answer would be very useful anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [Cannon Asia website](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html) (or any other Cannon website) and download the driver CAPT Printer Driver for Linux Version 2.60. Then execute the following steps:

1. Extract it to get a folder containing directory 64-bit_Driver/Debian, enter inside. 
   Install the deb file cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_amd64.deb through terminal:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install portreserve:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install portreserve
   ```
3. Restart the printer

   ```
   service cups restart
   ```
4. Add printer and start the Cannon Printer daemon.

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E
   sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0
   sudo service ccpd start
   sudo service ccpd status
   ```
5. Check the printer status

   ```
   captstatusui -P LBP2900
   ```

   If you are seeing the message “Ready to print”, you are done...